# flash builder 4.6 - native application issues -

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-builder, kinect

I'm trying to follow a tutorial here:

http://www.as3nui.com/airkinect-2-0-is-here/

which deals with developing an AirKinect application in Flash Builder 4.6, which I've installed. But when I follow the steps, a bunch of menu commands that the tutorial accesses are not available to me. I'm developing an Actionscript project. When I go to the project properties, and click the actionscript build path from the left, in the video there are 3 tabs - source path  tab, library tab, and native extensions tab, but I don't see native extensions tab. Furthermore, on the left, he has a menu called Actionscript build packaging - I do not have this. Lastly, he uses a command stage.nativeWindow.visible = false - when I use that it says it is an undefined property. I think that all of these issues have to do some how with the matter of native applications in flash builder, but I'm not sure. Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably started your project with the wrong settings. When you create a new ActionScript Project in Flash Builder 4.6, you can choose how it will run: in a browser or using AIR:

[image: New ActionScript Project dialog]

You should select the button "Desktop (runs in Adobe AIR)" under 'Application Type'. Then you will also see that native extensions tab in your project properties.

I don't know how to change an existing project into an AIR Desktop project but it should not be too difficult to create a new one and move your existing code into it.